# persistent connection by mail client

Tags: http, web, gmail

I tried understanding that is mail client like gmail and yahoo make a persistent connection with web server .?

Why I got this doubt because whenever I log in to any mail it will be open till I log out and I dont need to re-authenticate every time .

So I want to know what kind of connection really it makes with server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection is not actually persistence.

Whenever you authenticate to one of this mail clients it stores a persistent authentication cookie in your browser if you select remember me. This cookie holds your user information. As long as this cookie is valid web application doesn't prompt you for username and password. This cookie is deleted when log-out.

You can learn more about cookie [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie).